# React - Re-rendering child every time I change ref.current in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want the child component `Dashboard` to re-render every time I change `showOfferDescription.current`.

I must use `useRef` here - if I use `useState` the callback functions called by `game.events.on()` are ran every time using the initial value I put on that state (since they just do a copy of the initial value).

But on the other hand, if I use `useRef`, the child component `Dashboard` doesn't re-render when I change the refs I'm passing on `props`.

How do I force it to re-render? Would this be bad practice?

```
export default function App = () => {
    const showOfferDescription = useRef(false);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      // Must use a useRef variable here. If I use useState, the values don't update because
      // the callback function just keeps a copy to the initial value and not the current value  
      game.events.on('POINTEROVER', (id) => {
        showOfferDescription.current = true;
      })
  
      game.events.on('POINTEROUT', (id) => {
        showOfferDescription.current = false;
      })
  
    }, []);
  
    return (
      // Passing a ref to the child doesn't cause re-render on change. I want to trigger
      // a re-render in Dashboard everytime I change `showOfferDescription.current`
      <Dashboard 
        showOfferDescription={showOfferDescription} 
      />
    );
}
```

Comment: Store the state in useRef using useEffect. And in callback function use that ref to get the latest state.

Comment: @Filipe make sure that the dependency array is empty when using useState. Update the question with how you tried to use useState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem in this one:

```
export default function App = () => {
    const [showOfferDescription, setShowDescription] = useState(false);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      game.events.on('POINTEROVER', (id) => {
        setShowDescription(true);
      })
  
      game.events.on('POINTEROUT', (id) => {
        setShowDescription(false);
      })
  
    }, []);
  
    return (
      <Dashboard 
        showOfferDescription={showOfferDescription} 
      />
    );
}
```

Comment: My bad, this actually works. I had tried something with useState before but it wasn't working, but can't remember what I did different. Thanks!